# Split pandas on large white space

Tags: python, pandas, text, split

I need to split the following dataframe (a single column) into three, by large whitespace:

df =

```
0       boots 0330            on 31 mar          clp n...
1       tesco stores 6292     on 31 mar          clp n...
2       uniqlo                on 31 mar          clp n...
```

I need:

```
                 column_0      column_1          column_2
0       boots 0330            on 31 mar          clp n...
1       tesco stores 6292     on 31 mar          clp n...
2       uniqlo                on 31 mar          clp n...
```

I tried to split with `partition`:

```
df.str.partition(' on ')
```

but it gives:

```
                                                     0      1                            2
0                                  boots 0330              on   31 mar          clp nan nan
1                                  tesco stores 6292       on   31 mar          clp nan nan
2                                  uniqlo                  on   31 mar          clp nan nan
```

which misses the entire column 'on mar xx'. Any simple solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by regex `\s{2,}` - `2 or more whitespaces` and [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = s.str.split('\s{2,}', expand=True).add_prefix('column_')
print (df)

            column_0   column_1  column_2
0         boots 0330  on 31 mar  clp n...
1  tesco stores 6292  on 31 mar  clp n...
2             uniqlo  on 31 mar  clp n...
```